# SQL concatenate columns for search

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was looking for advice on the best way to implement search functionality over several columns.

I have a SQL server with columns for:

```
title
firstname
middlenames
lastname
maidenname
```

If a user searches for "John Smith" I need to look through all the columns for those values. Obviously, none of those columns will contain both parts of "John" and "Smith". I previously added the columns together eg

```
select * from PEOPLE where (firstname + ' ' + middlenames +  ' ' + lastname) = %@SEARCHVALUE%
```

However this prevents certain searches returning values because the wildcard does not match the search criteria.

Comment: Hint:  Full text search (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Thanks but can this be used over multiple columns dynamically? My understanding was that the column would have FTS enabled and it was only for a single one. Can values be spread over several?

Comment: . . Practically the first line in the documentation "A full-text index includes one or more character-based columns in a table. "  I'm not sure what you mean by "dynamic", though.

Answer (score 0):

If one of your fields can have null value you should do `CONCAT()` them as well.

```
SELECT * FROM PEOPLE WHERE CONCAT(firstname, ' ', middlenames, ' ', lastname) LIKE CONCAT('%',@SEARCHVALUE,'%')
```